# Get page by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Here is my js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        //do something
    }
    success: function(){
        //do something
    }
});
```

It gets test.html, how do I operate with received data inside success function?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like every *Ajax success handler*, the callback gets passed in the received data. The type of the data can vary, depending on the **dataType**.

In your case it's a *plain text* response (hopefully well HTML formatted). If so, you could just wrap the response into a jQuery constructor function and act on that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        //do something
    }
    success: function(data){
        // data contains the received HTML file
        $(data).find('.someclass').css('color', 'BADA55').appendTo('.somewhere');
    }
});
```

It actually only makes sense, that `.somewhere` represents an `<iframe>` element. This is because you cannot have multiple `<HTML>`, `<BODY>` or `<HEAD>` nodes in your markup. So appending a complete HTML file into a `<DIV>` would cause an invalid HTML markup and that is asking for trouble.

Comment: You should also set the dataType to html.

Comment: @Elad: jQuery will take care of you if you skip it. Base on the *MIME type* of the response. This should work fine here, but in general I agree. You should always set a dataType to be sure.